# trying to re-write a jquery slider be compatible with the v1.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to re-write this to be compatible with the jquery v1.7.1 It currently works with version 1.5

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">             
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#content-slipslide").slider({
       animate: true,
       change: handleSliderChange,
       slide: handleSliderSlide
    });
});
function handleSliderChange(e, ui) {
   var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollWidth") - $("#content-scroll").width();
   $("#content-scroll").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);
}
function handleSliderSlide(e, ui) {
   var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollWidth") - $("#content-scroll").width();
   $("#content-scroll").attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
}
</script>
```

Comment: So what did you exactly try so far? Can you give an example of what is missing, not working or what you want to be helped with?

Comment: `scrollWidth` and `scrollLeft` are properties, not attributes. Access them with the new-ish `.prop` method.

Comment: it worked with prop() but now instead of sliding along it doesn't move until mousedown. This happened when I changed it to .prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.6 (revised slightly in 1.6.1) introduced separate handling for properties over attributes (previously, both had been handled by the `attr()` method). This was convenient, but let to the idea that attributes and were properties were one and the same thing, which is untrue.

Since scroll properties are precisely that - properties - and so should be accessed via the `prop()` method.

The question doesn't warrant an explanation of the differences between properties and attributes are, but I am happy to edit the answer to provide some details if asked.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it worked with prop() but now instead of sliding along it doesn't move until mousedown. This happened when I changed it to .prop